Thune vs oseille vs pognon vs fric?
Recently learned a lot of synonyms for money from watching an episode of Lupin, but the dictionaries and translating tools haven't been too helpful in conveying the nuances between these terms, if any exist.
For instance I would not say "cash" and "dough" mean the same thing in English. They have overlapping but distinct meanings.
What are the nuances between oseille, thune, pognon, and fric?

I expect French has as many slang words for argent as Am.E. has for money.

Looking over that list, bucks is the only one that's widely used regularly. The rest are either unheard of or so egregiously slangy that they're mainly humorous and almost never used seriously. K and grand are widely used as synonyms for thousand though. And that's why I ask this question - because while cheddar may in some satirical context mean money, nobody could say that without getting a strange look in response and if a foreigner said it then people may literally not understand them. Are the terms I asked about closer to bucks or cabbage on the Actual Usage Scale?

I'm pretty sure all 4 I understood nowadays but I have a feeling fric & thune are more frequent nowadays, pognon and oseille more "old school".  One that's come up recently among youngsters is caillasse, not popular among older people (I had to look it up the first time I heard it, since then I've heard it).  If you're looking for one that's neutral slang understood by everyone I'd go for fric.

They are all slang for money, while 'cash' is not. The latter would be de l'argent liquide / du liquide or just du cash (informal).
Oseille is getting old fashioned in my opinion.
Thune, fric, pognon are still used and I don't perceive any significant nuance between them although thune is possibly more "street talk".
We can add flouze, blé, pèze, ronds, (pas un) radis, pépettes, grisbi (old) to that list, and numerous other terms more or less mainstream.
163 synonyms here.

Et sans doute encore bien d'autres ... mais pas vraiment de nuance.

Caillasse, maybe worth mentioning, recent & used by younger people. Worth visiting: Fric, pognon, flouze ou pèze : ce que cachent les mots de l'argent & Biff, ronds ou caillasse, Radis, avoine, blé ou oseille : depuis quand paie-t-on en légumes et en céréales ?

@None I didn't know caillasse but I see it is attested in 1904: Est-ce que la payse ne te donne pas de la caillasse, tant que tu en veux !

This is for France only:

oseille in the figurative sense is informal and colorful;
pognon is colloquial, suggesting a fistful of coins (pogne is colloquial for a fist);
thune is "traditional slang": in the cant of the professional beggars (early 19th C., say), it meant alms. As a child, I did not use the word; I thought it denoted a silver coin in the local parlance (Lorraine, Vosges). For the younger generations who revived it, it sounds s/what fashionable in its datedness;
fric is "Simonin slang": sounds like an import from the Maghreb, so early 20th C. Connotes more wealth, affluence, comfy income than cash money.

My li'l finger says the above should be understood in Belgium and Switzerland without translation. In contrast,
flouze is definitely from our colonial past; only becoming mainstream slang in the sixties.
